# How to save UIWebView content as .webarchive format?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, webarchive

I had been tried this library: https://github.com/stake/STWebArchiver
It's good, but if I access some web pages isn't well-formed, it would not be saved.

So, is there any way for me to try to save web page(s) as .webarchive on iOS devices?
Could somebody give me some advices?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot. `UIWebView` is not equal to the `WebView` class in Mac OS X. I recommend you try **[ASIWebPageRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/ASIWebPageRequest)**.

Answer (score -1):

For Webpage not well formatted, the libxml parser(which is the original STWebArchiver using) is not a good solution. So I update STWebArchiver with Regular Expression
like this

```
NSArray *pathsForImagesAndScripts = [self extractResourcesWithHTML:htmlContent regex:@"<(?:script|img).*src=[\"']((?!data:).*?)[\"']"];
```

checkout: [this](https://github.com/Fykec/STWebArchiver)